# How to install package from source on fedora in 2017?

Tags: fedora, dnf

What is the most clean way to install third party `tar.gz`'s to make it maintainable through `dnf`? I see no checkinstall in repos, but it should be a standard and fast way to do it. There is an article about creating RPMs, but it is way too complicated and doesn't cover just downloading and installing.

Comment: Usually you can find the most applications / libraries as `src.rpm`, which is source code, meant to be built with `rpmbuild -bb name.spec` → The result is rpm package(s) for "the build OS".  ......  Which  tar.gz's is it about ? ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen Usually you can find, that most applications doesn't even know about rpm and thinking that `linux` equals `.deb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will probably have the cleanest experience by not bothering to funnel the software through RPM; just build it locally into `/opt` or `/usr/local`.

But, if you really want it, there's FPM, which will create a quick and dirty package from just about anything. Find it at https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most clean way to install third party tar.gz's to make it maintainable through dnf?

The best way is to package it for Fedora, it it is not yet available in [Fedora packages](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/) nor from third party sources (rpm fusion, United RPMS, ...).

How to correctly make a package is described in the [packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines) including tutorials.

Once you will have the SRPM package, you can either rebuild it on your own (`rpmbuild --rebuild package.src.rpm`), or publish it either in official fedora package database, in [COPR](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/), or in other database).